# Blown Head gasket for triton

Tags: cylinder-head, gasket

My 2005 tritons overflow is bubbling every time I go to point A to B and sometimes coolant pours down to the floor I know that it’s a sign of a blown head gasket or an cracked head.. is it still safe to drive without damaging and if so what would it damage?

Comment: It doesn’t overheat usually.. it’s over heated twice because coolant must have ran low from pouring out of the overflow and it pours outside on the floor

Comment: possible duplicate, see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/67042/10976

Answer (score 2):

STOP DRIVING IT. Never drive a vehicle that overheats. I'm too new to comment and you haven't given enough detail to really prove its the head gasket. It could be as cheap and easy as replacing the thermostat to fix what you just described.  Watch my boy Scotty's video before you edit your question. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evpaTW2WJ5Y

Also what do you mean coolant pours down to the floor? Like inside the truck or on the ground outside?

Comment: This is more than a comment, but someone will say it is a poor answer...

Comment: Thats what I'm saying, but i'm too new to comment. And no one was telling him to stop driving it. So i did what i had to do

Comment: I voted for your answer, as I think it has more value than just a comment, may not be a perfect answer but most never are...